# cumulative_filtering won't allow multiple selection in yadcf

Tags: datatables, multipleselection, yadcf

When I use cumulative filtering it won't allow multiple selections because it filters out all the other options on that column rightaway.  I was too impatient and opened an issue but I think I should have asked here first.  Sorry about that.  If I am doing something wrong I should close the issue.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thats not quite accurate, if you will inspect the [showcase sample](http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/cumulative_filtering.html) (its first column multi select filter) you will notice that when selecting *Some Data 1* will keep *Some Data 11* available for selection from the filter. At the moment this behaviour is *By Design* ( my design :) ). I hope I will be able to look and think about your issue in the near future (busy recently)

p.s I'm the author of [yadcf](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf)

Comment: I am very much aware of the fact that you are the author and very greatfull for all the work you put in this project.  I wish I knew enough to contribute.

Comment: Wrote about being the author only for a *full disclosure* for other possible users :) , at the moment thats how yadcf behave.